# ReactNative interpolate equivalent in Flutter

Tags: react-native, flutter

Suppose I want to animate the radius(r) of a circle as following:

10 --- 20 --- 40 --- 10

In React Native, I can animate by

```
r.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, 0.33, 0.66, 1],
  outputRange: [10, 20, 40, 10],
});
```

In Flutter, I have to

```
Tween<double>(10,20)
  .animate(parent: controller,
            curve: Interval(
              0,
              0.33,
              curve: Curves.easeInOutBack,
            ),
          ),
    )
Tween<double>(20,40)
  .animate(parent: ...,
            curve: Interval(
              0.33
              0.66,
              curve: ...
            ),
          ),
    )
Tween<double>(40,10)
  .animate(parent: ...,
            curve: Interval(
              0.66,
              1.0,
              curve: ...
            ),
          ),
    )
```

Is the above the correct way to achieve it in Flutter? By correct I mean more idiomatically speaking.

Comment: check `TweenSequence` (or for even better result use `CatmullRomCurve` / `CatmullRomSpline`)

Comment: Awesome :). What a shame I didn't find this useful widget in the first place.. Maybe elaborate it a little in the answer so I can accept it.